# Is there a more general process to derive a characteristic equation for non-trivial circumstances?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

The way I was taught about a characteristic equation is essentially "try plugging in $e^{ \lambda t}$ and see what happens". But is that really all there is to it? That doesn't intuitively lead me to more advanced techniques like taking a matrix exponential and Jordon-blocking it for more complicated circumstances.

Is there a more formally generalized process to explain what is going on when you derive a characteristic equation that would allow you to derive non-polynomial characteristic equations like $ \sin( \lambda) - \log(t)$ just as an example? Or what about other "characteristic" equations where you try plugging in $ \lambda \log(t)$? Why is that also not something that can generate a characteristic equation? Can the process be generalized to account for other functions besides $e^{ \lambda t}$?

Comment: Note first that $\sin \lambda$ can be expressed as a linear combination of exponentials. The fact that the exponential function is a fixed point of the derivative is also relevant here.

Comment: The idea in more generality is to pass to a first order system and then conclude that you need to calculate $e^{At}$ or more generally $e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds}$.

Comment: So the solution to any differential equation is just $e^{ \int A(s)ds}$? Then what were all those Jordan blocks for?

Comment: @stackexchangequestions2 The solution to $x'=Ax,x(0)=x_0$ is $e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds} x_0$. You use the Jordan form of $B$ to compute a matrix exponential $e^B$ in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can try to generalize this idea. If you can find a function family $\phi(t,\vec C)$, and inserting this into the differential equation allows you to find expressions in the constants in $\vec C$ that do not depend on the time $t$, that when setting to zero reduce the equation to a triviality, then you can also call these conditions on $\vec C$ characteristic equations.

But in general this will be very hard to do, compared with the success of the family of exponential functions $\vec ve^{λt}$, $\vec C=(λ,\vec v)$, for linear DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: I think what is missing is incorporating this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicEquation.html. Not one of you mentioned any kind of determinant or $I- \lambda A$ equation, and in the non-linear case, the $A$ matrix may contain non-linear terms.

Comment: In the non-linear case you do not get a matrix equation at all. You will be lucky to get anything at all. The eigenvalues and vectors only give meaningful results for constant $A$.

Comment: No you have a matrix, it's just that it maybe contains variable terms or possibly time-dependent terms. I've seen this in research papers about delay differential equations and the method they use in a square matrix case is to invert it over a specific Banach space. There is some theorem in Lie group algebra used to generalize linear operators and this lets you construct matrix exponentials of combinations of differentials, scalars, variables, integrals or really any other linear operator that maps the space to itself.